# Django model.full_clean() allows invalid value for IntegerField

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I have a some models with inheritance that look something like this:

```
Class A(models.Model):
    some_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #other fields, not important

Class B(A):
    some_int = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(1000)])
```

Then I fire up the Django shell and do the following:

```
>>> obj = B()
>>> obj.some_text = 'foo'
>>> obj.some_int = 'bar'
>>> obj.full_clean()
```

And naturally I get:

```
>>> ValidationError: {'some_int': [u"'bar' value must be an integer."]}
```

Good. Then:

```
>>> obj.some_int = '   ' #whitespace
>>> obj.full_clean()
```

And I get:

```
>>> ValidationError: {'some_int': [u"'   ' value must be an integer."]}
```

Perfect. But then I try an empty string:

```
>>> obj.some_int = '' #empty string
>>> obj.full_clean()
```

No ValidationError is raised, but if I try to save the object:

```
>>> obj.save()
```

I get:

```
>>> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What's going on here? Is this correct behavior? How is Django checking to see if the value is a valid integer?

I really don't want to customize my model's clean() function to check for this, but it's starting to look like I have no choice.

EDIT: Django 1.6.5, Python 2.7.6, Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the reason of this behavior is commented in clean_fields method :

```
    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
    """
    Cleans all fields and raises a ValidationError containing message_dict
    of all validation errors if any occur.
    """
    if exclude is None:
        exclude = []

    errors = {}
    for f in self._meta.fields:
        if f.name in exclude:
            continue
        # Skip validation for empty fields with blank=True. The developer
        # is responsible for making sure they have a valid value.
        raw_value = getattr(self, f.attname)
        if f.blank and raw_value in f.empty_values:
            continue
        try:
            setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors[f.name] = e.error_list

    if errors:
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```

Comment: Welp...you're right. I imagine there's a very good reason for this that I can't fully appreciate at the moment. Still, seeing it explicitly written that I am responsible for validating an empty field with `blank=True` makes the solution feel less dirty/messy. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this behavior because you have `blank=True`. I agree with you that the behavior you're seeing is strange - it's a symptom of the fact that in Django *model* validation is tied up quite tightly with *form* validation, even though in principle they can be separate.

Assuming that you actually want `blank=True` and `null=True`, I wouldn't worry about this. Forms will do the right thing (convert the empty string in a form to a `NULL` value in the database), and the model and database won't actually let you save the invalid value. The only issue is that if you have data entry that doesn't involve Django forms, the error will get thrown at `save()` time rather than at `full_clean()` time.

Of course, if you don't want to allow `NULL` values for the field, just set `blank=False, null=False` and `full_clean()` will complain about the empty string just like you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately, the field must stay `blank=False, null=False`...and I do have data entry that doesn't involve Django forms. Looks like I'll have to check for this myself. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because you allowed your field to be blank (and also null).
so it is okay and it is valid.

If you don't want it to be that way, just remove the `blank=True` option or change it to `blank=False`

Comment: If "it is okay and it is valid", then why is an exception raised when I try to save the object? If I set the value to None, it works fine. It raises no validation errors when I call full_clean() and no value errors when I call save(). This only happens with an empty string.